# Django only reading some environmental values

Tags: python, django, docker, environment-variables

I have a Django project deployed with Docker, and now the project doesn't load all my environmental values specified in the **.env** file. Only some of them are read. This is my .env file:

```
DJANGO_DEBUG=changeme(1/0)
DB_NAME=changeme
DB_USER=changeme
DB_PASS=changeme
SECRET_KEY=changeme
EMAIL_PASSWORD=changeme
EMAIL=email@example.com
DOMAIN=example.com
```

And in **setting.py** I access the values that way:

```
DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', 0)))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com.'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

All the database related values are read properly as well as the secrey key. But the rest of the values are not read, and I don't understand why. Which could be the problem?

Comment: Which environment variable is not read? There is no `DB_HOST=changeme` in the `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not including some of the environmental variables in the *docker-compose.yml* file.

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - DJANGO_DEBUG=${DJANGO_DEBUG}
      - EMAIL=${EMAIL}
      - EMAIL_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=${DOMAIN}
      - CSRF_TRUSTED=${CSRF_TRUSTED}
    depends_on:
      - db
```

After including all the variables in the app > environment section, everything worked good!